# magento get the collection of the promotions

Tags: magento-1.7

Please if you can help me to get the collection of the current promotions rule i.e. catalog price rule and shopping cart price rule. I have some requirement of client and so want to interrelate both of them.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to get the catalog price and price rules rules by id,please see the fallowing example,

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load(1); 
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
echo $rule->getDiscountAmount();
```

and for price rule for shopping cart use

```
$rule = Mage::getModel('salesrule/rule')->load(1); 
$rule->setWebsiteIds("1"); 
echo $rule->getDiscountAmount();
```

i hope it may help you,thank you.